# Loop in <asp:formview> item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

I have a

> asp:formview

which is bound by SelectMethod in the code behind with a Stored Procedure. On my .aspx page all the Items are displayed with

```
> <%# Item.OrderID%>
```

and that is working fine. The problem is one of the item's value is comma separated. Column name is PeopleAssociated and its value is in string format like this:

```
Author | Joey Smith | ABC Technology | abc@abc.com | 67022 || Author | Ross Bing | ABCD Tech | cde@cde.com | 33533
```

Now if i just do

```
<%# Item.peopleAssocWithSubmission.Replace("||", "<br/>") %>
```

that will print the data somewhat i expect it to be but i want more control on what to print. I want to just print Name and Email address. I am wondering if i cam do a .split("||") and run a loop through array and print items only i wanted to print. Let me know if looping is possible in anyway.I am workign with asp webforms with vb.net

Comment: You mean pipe delimited. Yes, try the split, and then just display the fields that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a method that processes the string and returns it formatted the way you want...

Without a loop

```
public string formatPeopleAssocWithSubmission(string input)
{
    string[] inputArr = input.Split('|');
    return string.Join("<br/>", inputArr);
}
```

With a loop

```
public string formatPeopleAssocWithSubmission(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string[] inputArr = input.Split('|');

    foreach (string s in inputArr)
    {
        if (s == "Email")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s + "<br/>");
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then on the aspx

```
<%# formatPeopleAssocWithSubmission(Item.peopleAssocWithSubmission) %>
```

Comment: You are the man, that is exactly what i was looking for. I had the change the function little bit as per my needs but works as i expected. Thanks